# Is there a CLI or libary that allows inspecting non-UTF-8 ZIP file names?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, libraries, binary-files

I have a ZIP file which contains files whose names are not UTF-8 encoded. My GUI archive manager displays and extracts them just fine. I would like to programmatically get the binary representation of the names to inspect them, or dump them to a binary file (e.g. with a CLI tool). Is there a program or library that works on Linux that does this?

I have tried:

- `unzip` does not work, it replaces characters with `?`
- Python’s `zipfile` decodes to Unicode using a user-supplied encoding, but I want the result in binary to figure out the encoding